# Facebook Get Post Api

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a delay on facebook get, in post graph api, using php sdk

```
$facebook->api('pageId_postId','GET');
```

this is in foreach loop running approx 20 times.It gives result for the first four hits but this error after it and stops

```
Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request.
```

Answer (score 0):

What type of object are you looping over? Where did you get the IDs?

`Unsupported get request` usually means you're trying to access a path that doesn't exist (i.e /blah - where 'blah' isn't actually an object) or access a connection (such as comments, likes, etc) which doesn't exist on the object you're accessing

Comment: tried it with the same id in the loop. again 4 hits and then the same error but i was able to solve this. i was sending another $facebook->api request to event id and getting its attending event list. Removed it and it work.. guess facebook has somekind of Limit on get request from a system.

Comment: No, the rate limit has a specific error message about rate limiting, there's something else wrong with what you're doing